# Any open source software that I can put onto a Netgear wgt624 v3 router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, firmware, open-source

My Netgear wgt624 v3 router doesn't seem to be amazingly responsive any more, so before I buy another router, I'd like to try putting some open source software on the thing and see if it makes it better/passably usable.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database dd-wrt apparently doesn't have any support, nor the older "tomato".  Open-wrt... ...I can't tell whether it has anything useful.

Is there anything else I can try (including open-wrt, if I'm wrong about that being an option)?

Answer (score 1):

Check compatibility with openwrt and dd-wrt.  These are the common software to install on compatilbe routers.  Both distributions have lists of compatible routers.